# Removing data held in a table row and assigning it to a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `user_photos` which has the following structure:

```
   id
   img_url
   uploaded_on
   username
```

I also have a table called `users`, which has a column called `profile_pic`.

I have a PHP script which is called `change_dp.php`. The basic idea is that a user can upload photos and then on hover, they have a button called `Make display Picture` which when clicked, calls `change_dp.php`.

However, photos which users upload are stored in the `user_photos` table and the actual photo location is stored in this format (`img_url`):

```
user_data/user_photos/ronda2.jpg
```

user_data folder > user_photos > and then the file name.

However, in my `users` table, which is where `profile_pic` data is held, images are stored in this format in the `profile_pic` column:

```
ronda_rousey.jpg
```

**Issue**: The issue is that I need to execute an `UPDATE` query in order to allow a user to change their profile picture (What I need is to get the file name, and just the file name from `user_photos` and SET that to the `profile_pic` in the users table). But since the images are stored in different folders, I also need a way to copy the image from `user_photos` to `profile_pics` when the `Make Display Picture` button is clicked.

**How I think I should tackle this issue**:
My thinking was to get the data from `user_photos`, i.e. get the whole `img_url` - `user_data/user_photos/ronda2.jpg` - Obtain just the file name from this column (`ronda2.jpg`) and somehow find a way to copy that image to the `profile_pics` folder and store the file name (which would be assigned to a PHP var) in the in the `profile_pic` column in table `users`.

But I don't know how to remove the `user_data/user_photos/` from before a file name, and if this is even the best way to go about this issue.

Summary:

- profile pictures are found in `user_data folder > profile_pics > file name`.
- user uploaded photos are found in `user_data > user_photos > and then the whole path to the image followed by image name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the filename from a fullpath then something like this will work

```
$file = "user_data/user_photos/ronda2.jpg";
$arrPathInfo = pathinfo($file);

echo $arrPathInfo['basename'];
```

Comment: Ah, this works! I can now get the name of the image. But, do you know how I can copy an image from one folder to another using this PHP variable? This is what I plan to do (in plain English) - `if $arrPathInfo matches an image name in the user_photos folder, then copy that image to the profile_pics folder`?

Comment: Something like this should work copy($file, "profile_pics/$arrPathInfo['basename']");

Comment: missed the check if the file exists, easy with if (file_exists($file)) { //Copy image with code above }

Comment: I have the following: `$shortened_url = $arrPathInfo['basename'];          if (file_exists($file)) {
  copy($file, "user_data/profile_pics/$shortened_url");
}` - But it doesn't seem to copy the image to the other folder? I had to change  `"profile_pics/$arrPathInfo['basename']"` to `$shortened_url` because I was getting errors, works the same though.

Comment: $shortened_url = $arrPathInfo['basename']; if (file_exists($file)) { copy($file, "user_data/profile_pics/" . $shortened_url); } maybe. Otherwise you will have to debug. Maybe the paths are inccorect

Comment: Depending where your script is you may need to go up a level or something like that copy($file, "../user_data/profile_pics/" . $shortened_url);

Comment: I have tried `copy($file, "../profile_pics/" . $shortened_url);` Just to clarify, `change_dp.php` - Is in `www > inc > change_dp.php`. profile_pics folder is in `www > user_data > profile_pics`. And user_photos folder is in `www > user_data > user_photos`.

Comment: then you will need to go up two directories. copy("../../" . $file, "../../profile_pics/" . $shortened_url);

Comment: Hmm, even this doesn't seem to work. Nevertheless, you have already answered the question I asked, all this was additional help which you have provided, so thank you for that, appreciate it :)